# Is it possible to install Android OS on HTC Windows 8s?

Tags: android

Is it possible to change OS on HTC Windows 8s device?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to do this?

Comment: Irritated with Windows Phone OS.

Comment: Me too, it would probably be easier to sell the phone and buy an iPhone/Blackberry/Android instead... Not very helpful, I know.

Comment: @SushanGhimire could we help you resolve any of the irritations? Personally, I love Windows Phone, and can't get on with Android, and I appreciate that we each have individual preferences on these things...

Comment: Its about Android OS, not Windows Phone OS.

Comment: This question is about Android OS not Windows Phone OS. Should be asked at Android Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the OS is not officially supported.

It also doesn't seem to be unofficially supported at the moment. There is almost no XDA [development activity](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2007&nocache=1&z=5772111684545568) on the 8X or any other Windows Phone 8 device for that matter, so while it might be possible in the future to install Android, Ubuntu, Windows 8 RT, etc, it doesn't look like it will happen any time soon.

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not (currently?) possible, and might never be possible. Then again, never say never when software is involved. ;-)

For some background on why this is, have a look at [this article on WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-beefing-security-windows-phone-8). All this should make Windows Phone even more interesting for enterprise use, which I think it a good thing.